# Can't call on Whatsapp's desktop application

Tags: linux, whatsapp

Linux Mint 20.3

WhatsApp 2.22

On my Google Pixel 3 smartphonoe (**Android**) I has application **Whatsapp** and success call. Nice.

I start on Linux desktop application **WhatsApp**. And I can't call. Button "call" not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Whatsapp support article
[About desktop calling](https://faq.whatsapp.com/1022175071615394/?locale=en_US)
says this:

> Desktop calling is supported on:
>
> - Windows 10 64-bit version 1903 and newer
> - macOS 10.13 and newer

It seems you're out of luck on Linux (at least for the moment).